# How to bind click event to random li elements inside ul element in angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular6

```
     <ul>
       <li class="daily">some text </li>
       <li class="daily">some text </li>
       <li>Random li without daily class on it </li>
       <li>Random li without daily class on it </li>
       <li class="daily">some text </li>
       <li> Random li without daily class on it </li>
       <li class="daily">some text </li>
       <li>Random li without daily class on it </li>
       <li class="daily">some text </li>
       <li class="daily">some text </li>
       <li>Random li without daily class on it </li>
       <li class="daily">some text </li>
     </ul>
```

I have a component, whose template has several `ul` elements (the above is just one of them) and each has multiple `li` elements with `class="daily"` on random `<li>s`. I want to call a method `daily()` defined inside my component if any `li` is clicked (having "daily" class on it). How can I acheive this without attaching `(click)="daily()"` on each `li` element. 
Note: Here using *ngFor is a tedious way to bind click event to such a random series of `<li>s`.

Comment: Are you populating these `li`s manually or are you looping through them using `*ngFor`?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera I am doing it manually

Comment: Why would you want to do it?

Comment: @TomaszBłachut because I do not want to type (click)="daily()" at hundred places manually as I am not using *ngFor directive here.

Comment: @Stavm a project needs to be converted from jquery into angular 6 where each ul has variable number of li in it, thats why binding click event to each is hard and not productive, I think.

Comment: You can bind to ul and check `instanceof event.target`

Answer (score 8):

You can place a click on the `ul` and catch the clicked child element in your function.

**HTML:**

```
<ul (click)="onClick($event)">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
</ul>
<h2>{{elementClicked}}</h2>
```

**Component:**

```
  elementClicked = 'Click any of the list item below'

  onClick(e) {
    this.elementClicked = 'You clicked: ' + e.target.innerHTML;
  }
```

**DEMO:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktt1qj?file=app/list-overview-example.ts

Comment: But what in case I want click event bind to only first and last li elements or any other random in between?

Comment: one way would be to use a switch-case inside the click handler. your requirement is unclear and it looks like you're a victim of the xy problem. *The XY problem is a communication problem encountered in help desk and similar situations in which the real issue ("X") of the person asking for help is obscured, because instead of asking directly about issue X, they ask how to solve a secondary issue ("Y") which they believe will allow them to resolve issue X*

Answer (score 2):

Just make a function like `onClick` and call it on click by element like in example below:

```
<li class="daily" (click)="onClick('some text')">some text </li>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent{


    onClick(param){
      console.log(param);
      //Do something
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be:

**In Component**

```
values: string[] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

daily(value: string): void {
   // do some action with the passed value
}
```

**In HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li class="daily" *ngFor="let v of values" (click)="daily(v)">{{ v }}</li>
</ul>
```

There is only one (click) event binding and the function bound to that event accepts the value so you can do whatever you need within the *daily* method.

**Edit:** I don't have the reputation to comment on your question. I hope you see the edit. Why would you think it's not productive to bind the (click) event to the < li > element?

It's better to invest some time and refactor the code. Instead of having hundreds of < li > elements with the 'daily' class to it, its better to have a service that returns an array of objects (hard-coded or asynchronously). Those objects should have the values (in your case the numbers) and simplify the view by removing the hundreds of lines of unnecessary < li > with the one three lines shown above.

Still, on the long term, its better to read the values (hard-coded or asynchronously returned from server) of a service instead of copy-pasting them over and over.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This needs to be the correct answer. The answer with the click event on the ul works but it's not the best practice.